# Not returning ajax response?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Hi I am using django framework. The ajax response is not working.
I have tried the code as follows.
views.py

```
def ForgotUsername(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        email=request.POST['email']
        usr=User.objects.all()
        question=""
        for i in usr:
            if email in i.email:
                id_email=i.id
                que=securityquestions.objects.get(user_id=i.id)
                question+=que.question   
        q={'question':question}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(q),mimetype='application/json')

    else:
        return render(request,'registration/ForgotPassword.html')
```

Html:

```
$("#email1").change(function()
            {
                var emailstring = $("#email1").val();
                var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                if (!emailReg.test(emailstring))
                    {
                        $("#emailalert").html('<div class="alert alert-error"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">×</button>Not a valid Email</div>');
                        return false;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            type:'POST',data:{email:emailstring},
                            url:'/registration/ForgotUsername/',
                            datatype:'json',
                            success:function(data) {
                                alert("email exists");
                                alert(data);
                                $('#ques').val(data);
                            }
                        });
                        return true;
                    }

            });
```

In this id "email1" is the email input field name.
My ajax response is print the output in a aseparate page. It's not returning response to ajax. Help me to proceed

Comment: you should pass `csrf_token` . `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/`

Comment: In my form I added {% csrf_token %}

Comment: but you don't pass it.

Comment: could you give suggesstion to how to pass it

Comment: Can you paste the response you are getting on your Ajax call?

Comment: Did you mean the response in success function?

Comment: You said "My ajax response is print the output in a aseparate page. It's not returning response to ajax" - What this output says, please post here.

Comment: Actually I am doing this in on change function jquery. So when I give tab after entered email in input field, it should show the question in security question label. Instead when I click submit button it shows the question in separate page like "normal httpresponse"

Comment: {

    "question": "What is your best friend's last name?"

}   "this is the output in that page"

Comment: In that case: 1. Make sure that your change event is getting called, put some alert in the start of function. 2. Put an *error* handler in your ajax call [Jquery link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). 3. Put some print statements in your view code and see what is exactly returned from server.

Answer (score 1):

PASS csrf_token  .

Your AJAX response should be

```
var CSRF_TOKEN = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
$.ajax({
          type:'POST',data:{email:emailstring, csrfmiddlewaretoken: CSRF_TOKEN },
          url:'/registration/ForgotUsername/',
          datatype:'json',
          success:function(data) {
              alert("email exists");
              alert(data);
              $('#ques').val(data);
       }
```

Comment: Nice answer :), easy and practical.

Comment: yes i have added, but still I didn't get. Actually I have written it in on change event. In my form i have input email field, next to that security question get field to recover my password.

Comment: While am giving tab email validation error i shown.. but not the question is getting displayed in the security question lable field

Comment: set `DEBUG` to `True` in your settings . so you will get exact error .

Comment: U `can` use `from django.template.loader import render_to_string` `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut` . put print statements in views to debug it .

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that in fast way, not the best you can add {% csrf_token %} into your form and pass the whole form in your ajax request by serializing it:

```
var yourForm = $("#your-form-id");

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',data:yourForm.serialize(),
    url:'/registration/ForgotUsername/',
    datatype:'json',
    success:function(data) {
        alert("email exists");
        alert(data);
        $('#ques').val(data);
    }
});
```

Serialization will convert the all form elements including `csrf_token` into desired data format.

Comment: yes i have added, but still I didn't get. Actually I have written it in on change event. In my form i have input email field, next to that security question get field to recover my password

Comment: While am giving tab email validation error i shown.. but not the question is getting displayed in the security question lable field